# Why is my simple firebase program trying to connect to the auth emulator?

Tags: python, firebase

im getting the following error when running the simple python program:

> firebase_admin.exceptions.UnavailableError: Failed to establish a connection: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9099): Max retries exceeded with url: /identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects/fir-api-test2-72710/accounts:lookup (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001B28FC6C4F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

The python program I'm running that creates this error is very basic:

```
import json

# Firestore database
db = None

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # FIRESTORE INITIALISATION
    load_dotenv()

    firebase_permisisions = json.loads(os.getenv('FIREBASE_CREDS')) 
    cred = credentials.Certificate(firebase_permisisions)
    firebase_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
    db = firestore.client()

    print('getting user')
    # fails here
    user = auth.get_user('1234')

    print(user)
```

If my colleague runs this program on his machine it works.

Not sure why the connection pool is looking for the locahost?  If I run the auth emulator on my machine it will work but picks up emulator users.

Ive test straight after rebooting my machine, and reinstall firebase admin but issue persists.

I do use the firebase emulator for other firebase projects

If anyone has any ideas that would be great,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Worked out that for some reason i had 'FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST' set as environment variable. Now it works as expected